# Filtering the Grid in Magento

Tags: magento, filter, grid, adminhtml

I have made a custom grid in magento that displays saved video urls and its working. But i want to show only records where the `urlid` is for example `3` . Here is my `_prepareCollection` function

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    // Get and set the collection for the grid
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('drecomm_productvideo/video_collection');
    //what should i put in here, addFieldtoSelect?
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

my grid extends from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` and there is no `addFieldToFilter` function in that class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you want to create a permanent filter for your collection (meaning that you will not be able to remove it from your grid view) you should use `addFieldToFilter` to your collection object. This method is not a part of `grid` class, it's the part of collection class.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('drecomm_productvideo/video_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('urlid', 3);
```

Now if you want to just add a *default* filter for you collection (meaning that it will be applied from the start, but you'll be able to reset it and see all entries), you should use `setDefaultFilter()` method of your grid block.

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();

    //... your code
    $this->setDefaultFilter(array('urlid' => 3));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer its very helpful. I can wanted to customize it further can you let me know how can I put something link : $this->setDefaultFilter(array('real_order_id' =>('lt' => '100000229')));